# Не работает терминал в PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, консоль, phpstorm

После установки node.js не работает терминал в PhpStorm

> Cannot open Local Terminal Failed to start [C:\Program
> Files\Git\bin\sh.exe -login -i] in E:/Учеба/test
>
> Error running process: CreateProcess failed. Code 2
>
> See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in Explorer) for the details.

Comment: перезагрузись__

Comment: @nörbörnën это не помогает

Comment: ну, может быть поможет установка `Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502999/4496422